# how to display json data in html table using only java script and rows should be added and removed dynamically based on json data

Tags: javascript, html, json

### Create Object from JSON String

var text='{"employees":[' +'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';function addRow(tableID)
{obj = JSON.parse(text);for(i=0;i<=2;i++){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =obj.employees[i].firstName + " " + obj.employees[i].lastName; }}

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax to retrive is value mentioned here

```
 var text='{"employees":[' +'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';


function results(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.xyz=?123',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                var place = '<h1>'+item.location+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.id+'</br>';

                output.append(place);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
};
```

---

```
function addRow(tableID) 
{
  obj = JSON.parse(text);for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
  {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =obj.employees[i].firstName  
    + " " +  obj.employees[i].lastName; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. i have done it with only java script and json.  ill try with ajax

Comment: Glad you did .. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
 <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }
    table
    {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table th
    {
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    table th, table td
    {
        padding: 5px;
        border-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>  <script type="text/javascript" src="file.json"></script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
            var i=0;
        function addRow(tableID) {
      var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";

        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
         element2.value=customers[i];
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
            i++;

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

   </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>

   <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

                      <INPUT   type="button"value="DeleteRow" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
   </TABLE>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: i have posted HTML file and json file.

Comment: var customers= ["niku","haku","tiku"];